# Is sarpa worship and Naga worship different? What are the fruits of Snake worship?

Tags: worship, naga

Is sarpa worship and Naga worship different? What are the fruits of Snake worship?

In Hindu culture it is believed that snake is Pitru. So we should worship it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Hindu culture it is believed that snake is Pitru**

I don't think that this is true.Kashyapa and his wife Kadru created all the Nagas or Sarpas. And these Nagas are not the same as the Pitrus (Manes).

Usually the Panchami Tithis of a month are attributed to the Nagas or serpents. It is on this day the prayers done to them are believed to be the most effective. Hence we have the festival of [Naga Panchami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nag_Panchami).

Whereas, the Amavasyas (no moon days) are dedicated to the Pitrus.On this day we do  Pitru Tarpanams. For example see the ["Reverence to Pitrus on Amavasyas and benefits"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=22) & ["Adulation of Nag Devatas on every Panchami Day"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=12) chapters of the **Varaha Purana.**

**Is sarpa worship and Naga worship different? What are the fruits of Snake worship?**

Here is the [Sarpa Baadha Nivruti Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sarpa_Badha_Nivruthi_Stotram). Reading which is supposed to make one free from fear or troubles of snakes.

> 1.Anantho, vasuki sesha padmanabhascha kambala, Drutharashtra, sankha pala, thakshaka Kaliya sthadha
>
> Ananth, Vasuki, Adhi Sesha, Padmanabha, Kambala, Drutharashra,
>   Sankhapala, Thakshaka and Kaliya
>
> 2.Yethani **nava naamaani nagaanaan** cha mahathmaanaam, Sayam kale paden nithya, pratha kale viseshatha
>
> These names of nine snakes who are great, should be read daily in the
>   evening and specially in the mornings

As one can  see, in the Stotra "Sarpa" and "Naga" are used synonymously. So, I don't think that "worship of nagas" and "worship of sarpas" are two different things.

Few more verses from the stotra:

> 3. Narmadhayai nama, pratha Narmadhatai Namo nis, Namosthu Narmadhe thubhyam thrahi maam visha sarpatha.
>
> Salutations to Narmadha, Salutations to Narmadha in the morning and
>   at night, I salute you Narmadha and pray, **please save me from
>   poisonous serpents.**
>
> 4.Asitham chaarthimandham cha suneedhim chapi ya smareth, Diva vaa yadhi vaa rathrou naasya sarpa bhayam bhaveth.
>
> Remembering about Asitha, Arthimandha and Suneethi, In the day time
>   or also night, **there would not be any fear against snakes**

Thus,generally, to remove all kinds of fears and dangers from snakes are the main objectives of a Sarpa Puja.

Further fruits are found in the chapter of the Varaha Purana mentioned above.

> Brahma advised the serpents as a race to refrain from the areas where
>   herbs, medicinal plants and Kites fly on the Sky which have a powerful
>   eyesight from far off distances. Unfortunately, even the well meaning
>   serpents of non-poisonous type are hunted out and killed by human
>   beings. But those remaining type are venerated **especially girls
>   desirous of marrying good husbands and women craving for children** by
>   providing milk and eats. Come Naga Panchami, especially in the week
>   following Deepavali celebrations, **women observe fast and refrain from
>   eating sour and milk preparations of food in several parts of Bharat
>   till date.**

So,marriage for unmarried girls and children for those ladies who don't have one are  also the fruits of a Sarpa Puja.

Comment: Sarpa is a serpent. Naga is a snake. There are different. Nagas are a sub set of Sarpas. Vasuki is the king of snakes and Takshaka is the king of serpents. In 4th shloka, it should be translated into serpents or cobras. But yes, words nagas and sarpas are used as synonyms.But they both are different

Comment: Nagas are one which can rise head like cobra.  These category is called Nagas.  head among nagas is takshaka <BR> Sarpas which cannot raise the head is called snake, head among sarpas is vasuki..